# Laravel - Select just one row from pivot table and return data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, pivot-table

Currently, for a user, I can return all `matches` correctly.

```
public function getMatches()
{
    $matches = Criteria::whereUserId( Auth::id() )
    ->has('alerts')
    ->with('alerts.location', 'alerts.user.companies')
    ->get();

    $this->layout->content = View::make('users.alert.matches', 
        array('matches' => $matches));
}
```

**Relationship:**

A `Criteria` belongsToMany `Alerts` and an `Alert` belongsToMany `Criterias`.

**Problem:**

If the user wishes to see more information about a certain match, I want to `get` just that result from the database. On my view, I can access the `criteria_id` inside the first `forloop`, and the alert_id inside the second `forloop`.

```
@foreach($matches as $match)
    {{$match->id}}
        @foreach($match->alerts as $alert)
            {{$alert->id}}
        @endforeach
@endforeach
```

But how can I use these variables to select just one pivot table match that the user wants to view more information about?

If a user was to select a certain {{$alert->id}}, how do I find which criteria_id relates to that alert_id, and then query the database to return the just that row of information, both from the `criteria` table and `alert` table, along with the `with->` statement shown above.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can include the data in your pivot table to your eager loading, like this:

```
public function getMatches()
{
    $matches = Criteria::whereUserId( Auth::id() )
    ->has('alerts')
    ->with('alerts.location', 'alerts.user.companies')
    ->withPivot('foo', 'bar'); //pivot table columns you need from pivot table criteria_alert
    ->get();

    $this->layout->content = View::make('users.alert.matches', 
        array('matches' => $matches));
}
```

And access it like this:

```
@foreach($matches as $match)
    {{$match->id}}
        @foreach($match->alerts as $alert)
            {{$match->pivot->foo}} // pivot table data
            {{$alert->id}}
        @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Check out the [laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables) for more details.

Also, this might help you simplify your code:

```
$matches = Auth::user()->with('criterias', 'criterias.alert')->get();
```

With your criteria to alert relationship like this:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('Alert')->withPivot('foo', 'bar');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Kazma, thank you for your reply. I slightly modified your code but it worked exactly how I needed it to. How would I now query the database with just the criteria_id and alert_id of one result?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to get the criteria data and alert data with criteria_id and alert_id. To do that, you can use your Eloquent Models with its find function, like Criteria::find($criteria_id) and Alert::find($alert_id)

Comment: Now you've shown me how to access an $alert_id with its associated $criteria_id, I now want to get just those rows. They're linked by a pivot table and so I want to, for example, Select * on alert_criteria where alert_id = $alert_id and criteria_id = $criteria_id.

Comment: You can use the pivot function

$criteria = Criteria::find($criteria_id);

foreach ($criteria->alert as $alert)
{
    echo $alert->pivot->foo;
}